# Angular JS accordion bug

Tags: angularjs

Here is my html code but I think ng-init isn't working.

```
     <div ng-init="accordion=1">
        <h3 class="accordion" ng-class="{active:accordion==1}">
           <a href ng-click="accordion = 1">Section 1</a>
        </h3>
        <p class="accordion-content" ng-show="accordion==1">Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using</p>

        <h3 class="accordion" ng-class="{active:accordion==2}">
           <a href ng-click="accordion = 2">Section 2</a>
        </h3>
        <p class="accordion-content" ng-show="accordion==2">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using</p>

        <h3 class="accordion" ng-class="{active:accordion==3}">
           <a href ng-click="accordion = 3">Section 3</a>
        </h3>
        <p class="accordion-content" ng-show="accordion==3">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form</p>
     </div>
```

I hope this could hope work as follow at the first time but it isn't working properly

[image]

But it shows like this.

[image]

I'm sure there might be no problem in js and styling work.

Please have a look here. 
https://jsfiddle.net/koaqayb3/11/

I have one module already and would like to know how to integrate both of these.

var module = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch','ngScrollbars','']);

var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if possible then plz share jsfiddle link

Comment: do you get any errors in console?

Comment: Your code is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/23522/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/koaqayb3/9/

Comment: As you can see on my fiddle I have already one module so I want to integrate it.  If I comment the first line in Javascript it is working but if I comment second then it isnt working.

Comment: Your fiddle is also working fine for your problem you defined above. What is the problem you are facing now?

Comment: Your code is working fine in fiddle.

Comment: Please have a look again

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it for you. You declared that your module has some dependencies for other modules, which you did not include in your fiddle. I just removed the dependencies in your module declaration like this:

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/koaqayb3/13/

Comment: Thanks but I need that dependencies due to other functionalities. What can I do then?

Comment: You can have them in your real code, where you have the actual modules for the dependencies in javascript files like ng-animate.js and so on. But in the fiddle you did not include the dependency files that you declared in your own module declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle is not working because of the module dependencies defined inside

`var module = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch','ngScrollbars']);`

the app cannot got `'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch','ngScrollbars'` these dependencies in your fiddle remove them and it seems working fine.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsalaat/koaqayb3/14/)

Hope it helps

Comment: But I need that dependencies due to other functionalities. then what can  I do?

Comment: You can simply bind this template to the module in which you are working i.e `myApp`. Please wait I'll edit my answer and define you the steps.

Comment: @David please tell me where is this accordion template html is located in your project.

Comment: No I mean which html file your accordion is defined. Your code is working but just have to be in a page where angular is working.. Try `{{1+1}}` inside your accordion template if it does not display `2` it means your template does not have angular in action. :)